# My "main content" starts at the end of my sidebar... help!

Tags: css, css-float, phpbb, phpbb3

Ok, please look at my problem:

http://phone7forum.com/viewforum.php?f=2

http://phone7forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4

I've been editing a phpBB forum and adding in all of my css customizations and I've gotten pretty far along, but you can see in the 2 pages above the problem I'm faced with. My custom "main content" box starts out fine at first and sits exactly where i want it to at the top middle of the page, but when i stick the actual phpBB "forum code" inside it, the forum content will start where my left sidebar ends (way down at the bottom of the page).

My website is a "fluid width" website. The "left sidebar" is floated to the left, has a width of 300px, and height 100%. The "main content" has a left margin of 345px to push it past the sidebar so it will sit to the right of it. So thats my setup and it seemed to be working perfectly fine for me until i started adding in "forum content".  Does anyone have any idea on how to fix? Do you guys think that the problem exists in the forum's existing css/markup or is it a problem that I've created in the way I've layed out my website?

Here are screen shots of what my problem is (if for some reason you see something else in your browser):

http://phone7forum.com/images/1st_page_wrong.jpg

http://phone7forum.com/images/2nd_page_wrong.jpg

Here's how they should look, or what I'm trying to do (compliments of photoshop):

http://phone7forum.com/images/1st_page_right.jpg

http://phone7forum.com/images/2nd_page_right.jpg

I'm desperate for help! Thanks guys for looking!!

Comment: What browser are you using?  It looks okay to me - I'm using Firefox (version 3.6.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `content` `div` dosen't float left. Can you just add `float: left` and remove the left `margin`?

**update**

Muhaahaa, I found it:

```
html body#phpbb.section-viewforum div#main_wrap div#content div#content2 div#mybox_wrapper div#mybox-wrapper-content div#mybox-wrapper-content-inner div.forumbg div.inner span.corners-bottom
```

has a clearing. Remove it and all will be fine. :D